# JNI system loadlibrary

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am developing an app on Android using JNI.
My native code mylib.so depends on a.so.
When I use System.loadlibrary() I want to know do I need to load a.so too?

Thanks.

YL

Comment: No. You need only to load libraries that contain JNI native methods. Those libraries in turn will load whatever further libraries they are dynamically linked to.

Answer (score -1):

I think [this example on github](https://github.com/dhaniram-kshirsagar/android-ndk-curl) that I had written way back for loading static linked library and its dependencies will give you some more idea. In general, you only have to specify the main lib [in my case it was curl lib] and the System.loadlibrary will take care of loading dependencies.